# What makes a page not take up the entire width of the body?

Tags: html, css

What makes a page not take up the entire width of the body? [Here's a picture to demonstrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ims70.png).

Pretty much the whole thing that's going on in my style:

```
body {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #7F7F7F;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1400px;
}
```

If you need anymore code, just ask. I think that's all the code I have that would have any effect on the matter.

Update 07/19/17:
I tried removing the "width: 80%" and I got the same results. In fact, I tried adding a paragraph excluded from a container, and the paragraph didn't even want to go to the very-right side of the body. [See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGzya.png)

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] please

Comment: Because your container has a width of 80% set?

Comment: @funkysoul I wish. I removed the width of 80%, but the same result happened.

Comment: @HeadGam3z's dont remove just replace with 100% or 100vw

Comment: @funkysoul Apologies for the confusion; I actually have tried both. The same results remain.

Comment: Show some code. Posting screenshots only shows us your issue, but does not help us in anyway to troubleshoot the problem. It is evident that setting `width: 100%`, as many have suggested, did not work—and we are really shooting in the dark unless you share some of your code. Ideally, you should be sharing your markup and styles in a minimal, concrete and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Your container width is set to 80%, so the page content within the container will only ever cover 80% of the body of the page.

Comment: True, but the container is only containing the text and images. The background (or background colors) are independent of the container. (See http://i.imgur.com/cQuJ7XI.png for an example of a paragraph excluded from a container)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are telling it not to with this: width: 80%;

If you want it full page, then the container needs to be full width (either 100%, or 100vw will work). "vw" wont care about the size of the parent. It will break outside the parent as needed in order to fill the screen width.

So, if you want to keep the container at 80%, but still have the image full page width, use "vw" instead of "%".

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, that doesn't seem to be the case. I tried inserting a paragraph outside of the container, and it still shows up oddly. (See http://i.imgur.com/cQuJ7XI.png)